# Using variables returned from infinite loop function in another file

Tags: python

I know the title may sound a bit confusing but here is my struggle:

I have two separate files, one is only for gathering data and converting (data_.py) it and the second is main program file (main_.py). The core function in data_.py looks like this (it is simplified ofc):

```
def some_function():
    #here some python magic happens
  while True:
    #more magic
    return var1, var2, var3
```

variables are updated every few seconds. Now Im trying to use them in main_.py, so far I have this:

```
import data_

var1, var2, var3 = data_.some_function()
```

and when I print my variables everything works, but of course they are imported only once and not updated after.

I've tried doing this:

```
import data_

while True:
    var1, var2, var3 = data_.some_function()
    print(var1, var2, var3)
```

to update them as frequently as possible, yet they aren't updating for some reason.

Is there a way to achieve this while keeping function in separate files?

Comment: what you are looking for is called generators and yield keyword is used instead of return. search generators in python. feel free to ask any doubt

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, but this might sound like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Try using `yield` instead of return

Comment: look into `cycle` from itertools as well as yield if that fits your problem better. Also, if you need the vats to be dynamic and generated on the fly, look into asyncio for concurrent code. Although, if you're struggling with concepts like generators, you might want to hold off on asyncio. But definetly look into something like cycle([var1, var2, var3])

Comment: I've tried using yield here, but it raises this: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3), any suggestions? can I yield only one var at once ot something?

Comment: yes yield will get you one value at a time not all three

Comment: read about generators https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for is generator. Below is sudo code for your case

you define you function like this. you gather and convert data and when a chunk of data is ready to be processed you give that to other code calling this function. But this is not parallel processing. your some_function() pauses until that data is being processed.

```py
def some_function():
    #here some python magic happens
    while True:
        #more magic
        yield var1, var2, var3
```

then you use this function like below. the loop continues until while loop on some_function is not finished

```py
for var1,var2,var3 in some_function():
    print(var1, var2, var3)
```

**Working Example**

```py
def some_function():
    for x1, x2 in zip(range(1000),range(0,2000,2)):
        yield x1,x2


for x1,x2 in some_function():
    print(x1,x2)
```